# account still being banned...after improvements being made

Tags: discussion

My account, some weeks ago was banned due to bad posts/questions quality. Before the ban I had a reputation of 15, after the bad posts it dropped to 7, and now, after improving the posts, **my reputation is 17**, better than ever.

Despite this my account is still banned. The only thing I can think of is the fact that there is a post left where I got a -1, and so fixing that my account will be reinstated again.

But...is it possible that just one question affects if the account remains banned or not-the other questions seems to be Ok-no negative reputation, it is either 0(the vast majority) or 1.

Comment: I haven't looked yet, but if the ban was not lifted with only one -1 question remaining, it's probably due to deleted questions. You should ask a moderator to undelete [some of] them so you have the chance to improve those.

Comment: Yes, your reputation improved. But apparently the majority comes from accepting answers to your questions. Try to contribute a bit more to the community. Answer questions of others. Improve content through suggested edits. Etc.

Comment: Anyway, giving answers to answers to others is not so easy for me-much of the questions are directed for experience developers-I am not such.